# Java: Dijkstra algorithm with ThreadPool and CountDownLatch causes out of bounds exception

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, dijkstra

This is based on my previous question: [Wait in a loop until tasks of ThreadPoolExecutor are done before continuing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974820/java-wait-in-a-loop-until-tasks-of-threadpoolexecutor-are-done-before-continuin?noredirect=1#comment100486376_56974820)

I'm trying to make a Dijkstra algorithm parallel. 
I implemented a CountDownLatch to wait for all tasks to finish. Each task looks at a certain set of edges connected to the current node in the iteration. So 8 edges and 2 threads means each task will look at 4 edges. After all tasks are done we will continue with the next node.

For some reason the start and end point for the index(number of connected edges) sometimes goes higher than the available edges. I had this problem before the CountDownLatch and I figured it was because of the tasks not waiting to finish before we continue.

To look at some debug lines I put a Thread.Sleep(100) in to look at the output, I noticed that the array does not go out of bounds when I slow things down.

Finally I noticed the loop gets stuck on node 0, the source. This should not be possible because we start at this node and set visited true. I don't know if this because of the other errors or another bug in my code.

This function is called once and will loop through all the nodes in the graph:

```
public void apply(int numberOfThreads) {
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads + 1);
        CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(numberOfThreads);

        class DijkstraTask implements Runnable {

            private int start;
            private int end;
            private final CountDownLatch cdl;

            public DijkstraTask(int start, int end, CountDownLatch cdl) {
                this.start = start;
                this.end = end;
                this.cdl = cdl;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                calculateShortestDistances(start, end, cdl);
            }
        }

        currentNode = 0;
        this.nodes[0].setDistanceFromSource(0);

        // Visit every node, in order of stored distance
        for (int i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
            // Loop round the edges that are joined to the current node
            currentNodeEdges = this.nodes[currentNode].getEdges();

            int edgesPerThread = currentNodeEdges.size() / numberOfThreads;
            int modulo = currentNodeEdges.size() % numberOfThreads;

            System.out.println(i);

            //Add task for each node
            for (int t = 0; t < numberOfThreads; t++) {
                int start = edgesPerThread * t;
                int end = edgesPerThread * (t + 1);

                executor.execute(new DijkstraTask(start, end, cdl));
                System.out.println("Start: " + start + ". End: " + end + ". Total: " + currentNodeEdges.size());

               //If we have a modulo we will add another task to look at the remaining edges
                if (modulo > 0 && numberOfThreads == (t + 1)) {
                    start = edgesPerThread * (t + 1);
                    end = edgesPerThread * (t + 1) + modulo;

                    executor.execute(new DijkstraTask(start, end, cdl));
                    System.out.println("Modulo start: " + start + ". End: " + end + ". Total: " + currentNodeEdges.size());
                }
            }
            //wait for all threads to finish
            try {
                cdl.await();
                System.out.println("-all done-");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            // All neighbours are checked so this node is now visited
            nodes[currentNode].setVisited(true);

            //Look through the results of the tasks and get the next node that is closest by
            currentNode = getNodeShortestDistanced();
        }

        executor.shutdown();
    }
```

The following function is called by the task, it will proccess the connected eges from the start index to end index:

```
public void calculateShortestDistances(int start, int end, CountDownLatch cdl) {

        //Process the edges
        for (int joinedEdge = start; joinedEdge < end; joinedEdge++) {
            // Array goes out of bounds here!
            int neighbourIndex = currentNodeEdges.get(joinedEdge).getNeighbourIndex(currentNode);

            // Only interested in an unvisited neighbour
            if (!this.nodes[neighbourIndex].isVisited()) {
                // Calculate the tentative distance for the neighbour
                int tentative = this.nodes[currentNode].getDistanceFromSource() + currentNodeEdges.get(joinedEdge).getLength();
                // Overwrite if the tentative distance is less than what's currently stored
                if (tentative < nodes[neighbourIndex].getDistanceFromSource()) {
                    nodes[neighbourIndex].setDistanceFromSource(tentative);
                }
            }
        }

        cdl.countDown();
    }
```

Thanks for the help so far!

Edit: I added the stack trace:

`````
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-388" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 9
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at ThreadPool.CalculatePerVertice.calculateShortestDistances(CalculatePerVertice.java:136)
    at ThreadPool.CalculatePerVertice$1DijkstraTask.run(CalculatePerVertice.java:76)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    ````
`````

Comment: From a start, you only set current node as visited once you started the subtasks, which means they aren't guaranteed to observe it as "visited". Second, if you have a modulo task, you should count down one more time to get all the results. For instance, for 9 edges and `numberOfThreads = 5` you'll get 6 tasks, but latch will release when first five is done, and not wait for sixth. Likely, the last part is exactly why there's a problem.

Comment: And since you have the exception (at least sometimes), please include its stack trace, so the problem is complete. Right now it's not obvious where the exception might be.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I added the stack trace!

Comment: Ah. It's simpler than I expected (I think). Look, if `currentNodeEdges == 9` and `numberOfTreads == 5`, then `edgesPerThread == 1` and `max(t) == 4`. Then, `modulo == 4`, and `moduloEnd = edgesPerThread * (t+1) + modulo`, so `moduloEnd = 1 * (4+1) + 4`. Which is `9`, and it's out of bounds. It should be `8` tops.